# Vue router routes are not work in MEVN stack after build project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router

I Created a Vue application as my project. That works fine on the development server but it is not working after the build.

This is my vue router ‘s index file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard.vue'
import ViewOrder from '../views/ViewOrder.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path:'/dashboard',
    name:'Dashboard',
    component:Dashboard
  },
  {
    path:'/vieworder/:orderid',
    name:'ViewOrder',
    component:ViewOrder,
    props:true
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

This is my props section in the vieworder route.

```
 props:['orderid'],
```

This is my function for open that view in component

```
 viewOrderData(){
        if(this.selectedorder.length == 1){
          var routeData = this.$router.resolve({name:"ViewOrder",params:{orderid:this.selectedorder[0]._id}});
          window.open(routeData.href,'_blank')
        }
      }
```

This is my Vue.config.js file

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  outputDir:path.resolve(__dirname,'../application/public'),
  devServer:{
    proxy:{
      '/api':{
        target:'http://localhost:3000'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use Express as server,
Mongoose to database management,
axios and bodiparser to communicate